# Capture data from SCADA system into HDFS(Hadoop DataLake) for analytics

Tags: stream, spark-streaming, scada, data-lake

I am looking for a way where I can capture the PLC data from SCADA application in real time and store in hdfs (of a data lake) for analytics on it.

If it can be done, what are the possible ways to do it?

Any help or guidance will be really helpful.